# OneToMany - ManyToOne relationship in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to make oneTOMany - manytoone relation

I have experienced in making ManytoMany relationship,but

OneToMany is difficult and not get success.

Could you check my cord?
One SiteData has multiple feedData

```
class SiteData
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FeedData", mappedBy="siteId", cascade={"persist"})
     */

    private $feedIds;



class FeedData
{   
  /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\TopBundle\Entity\SiteData",inversedBy="site")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="site_feed")
     * )
     */

    private $siteId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try so:

```
class SiteData
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\TopBundle\Entity\FeedData", mappedBy="siteId", cascade={"persist"})
     */

    private $feedIds;



class FeedData
{   
  /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\TopBundle\Entity\SiteData",inversedBy="feedIds")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="site_feed")
     * )
     */

    private $siteId;
```